# iOS - CIImage autoAdjustmentFilters leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, core-image

I'm using the auto enhance feature to improve a lot of images.

But it seems there is a big leak, so here's the code I'm using :

```
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

@implementation UIImage (AutoEnhanced)
- (UIImage *)autoEnhancedImage
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        CIImage *ciOriginal = self.CIImage;
        if(!ciOriginal) {
            ciOriginal = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:self.CGImage];
        }
        NSDictionary *options = @{ CIDetectorImageOrientation : @(self.CGImagePropertyOrientation)};
        NSArray *adjustments = [ciOriginal autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions:options];
        for (CIFilter *filter in adjustments) {
            [filter setValue:ciOriginal forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
            ciOriginal = filter.outputImage;
        }
        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
        CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:ciOriginal fromRect:ciOriginal.extent];
        UIImage *enhancedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
        CGImageRelease(cgImage);
        return enhancedImage;
    }
}

- (CGImagePropertyOrientation)CGImagePropertyOrientation
{
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationUp;
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationUpMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationDown;
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationDownMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationLeftMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationRight;
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationRightMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationLeft;
    }
}
@end
```

And here's the log from Instruments :

[image]

Even with an autoreleasepool, I can't fix it. Any idea would be very much appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: First thing I always check is how you are using `CIContext` - and you're creating a new context for every image. That's a big no-no, at least performance-wise. Try sharing a single context. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer ! Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue though :( ..